# JavaScript fetch request body parameters not received

Tags: javascript, request, fetch, put, insomnia

**Context:**
I am trying to send a put request to a server using JavaScript and fetch from an html file I'm writing.

**Problem:**
The request I made is working in Insomnia, but when I try to send it from an html it isn't properly received. The code was generated by Insomnia also.
When I send it from the html the request is sent, and I get an ok back, but the server doesn't complete the task in the request, leading me to believe that it wasn't received or I missed something.
When trying to send the request, the console shows a response, that says "ok", 200, etc., but also has a "bodyUsed: false" part.

The function generated by Insomnia:

```js
fetch("url", {
  "method": "PUT",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "body": {
    "name": "name",
    "desc": "description"
  }
})
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

**Question(s):**
Is there anything wrong with the code? How does the server receive the request but not the body? Does the "bodyUsed: false" message mean that the request's body was ignored for some reason? Could this all be the server's fault?

Disclaimer:
I am a bit new to web development, so forgive me if I miss some obvious point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep `"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and your server is configured that way, you should send your data using a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) like this:

```js
var formData = new FormData(); 
formData.append('name', 'Chris');
formData.append('descr', 'description');

fetch("url", {
  "method": "PUT",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "body": formData
})
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is still present.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('name', 'name value');
formData.append('desc', 'description value');

fetch('url', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    body: formData
}).then(rawResponse => rawResponse.json())// or rawResponse.text() to get simple string
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Comment: I don't think I need credentials, but I checked and the results were the same.
Also: the browser gives an error without the header.
I tried to use formData, but sadly, it didn't help.

Comment: `credentials: 'same-origin'` I used to get cookies from the server, other way the client ignores them.
The true is I copy paste a code from an application, so I make sure it’s work, perhaps I ignore you were using a PUT not a POST method.